# How to create dynamic star rating based on value in array object?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a for loop inside td but i am getting error.

The product object has a rating, and I need to create a number of star using fontawesome based on the rating in the object

```
{
  productId: 2, 
  productName: 'Garden Cart',
  productCode: 'gdn 0011',
  available: 'March 19, 2019',
  price: '19.95',
  rating: 4,
},
```

```
let product = this.state.products.map((x) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>{x.productName}</td>
      <td>{x.productCode}</td>
      <td>{x.available}</td>
      <td>{x.price}</td>
      <td>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i> //I need to create 4 star based on the object
      </td>
    </tr>
  )
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an empty array with N element and map over it:

```
{[...new Array(4)].map(() => <i class="fas fa-star"></i>)}
```

Your code should look like this:

```js
let product = this.state.products.map((x) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>{x.productName}</td>
      <td>{x.productCode}</td>
      <td>{x.available}</td>
      <td>{x.price}</td>
      <td>
        {[...new Array(x.rating)].map(_ => <i className="fas fa-star"></i>)}
      </td>
    </tr>
  )
});
```